# Spring's JdbcTemplate and Transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

When using JdbcTemplate, do I need to explicitly configure transactions?

My code layout looks like the following:

I will have a UserDao that will be injected into my UserService, and then my Controllers will make calls on methods in my UserService.

I want to keep things as simple as possible transaction wise, and I don't need multiple database calls to span a transaction.

By default, do I have to do anything in my configuration file or use a `@Transaction` annotation anywhere?

Now say in my controller I need to make 2 calls on my userService and accountService, could I explicitly wrap it in a transaction somehow?

```
userService.updateUser(user);
accountService.updateXXX(...);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, `JdbcTemplate` is not a substitute for transaction management.  You still benefit from database transactions, so `userService.updateUser` will operate in a *database* transaction, but if `accountService.updateXXX` fails, `userService.updateUser` will *not* rollback.

If you don't want to use AOP, you can use [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) instead.  See [programmatic transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) in the [Spring Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

One pattern I've seen before is for the MVC controller class to invoke a business service, which encapsulates the operation.  The method of the business class could then be annotated `@Transactional`.

Comment: wow, that's allot of code for a transaction, @Transactional sure makes it less boilerplate to write!

Comment: It is, but it's quite useful if you need to access the `TransactionStatus`.

Comment: +1 for the business service idea.  IMHO, life would be easier if everyone did this.

Comment: I just want to know how PlatformTransactionManager  make a relationship  with jdbcTemplate, because they have a Datasource

Comment: How to use `AOP` with `jdbcTemplate`? I seen some examples with require a `JpaTransactionManager` depdendency, but is JPA correct for `jdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 17):

If your controller wants to do several things with users and accounts and have all that happen within one transaction, then you should have a service with one method that does all that stuff. Creating one service per DAO is not a great idea, because you end up with do-nothing wrappers around DAOs and processing will be slow because the database will have to create a separate transaction for each call to a DAO, you're making it do a lot more work than it should have to.

The service should provide functionality to the controller or whoever else is calling it. I try to create services with the idea that the service provides specific functions useful to a certain type of user.

Comment: +1 seconded.  This makes several things easier, including testing, and makes it easy if you need to expose any functionality to another view other than a controller (a REST API, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Spring `JdbcTemplate` is not aware about the transactions *at all*. If you have not configured transactions in any way - programmatically, usually via `PlatformTransactionManager` or `TransactionTemplate` (which is just a more high level api for `PlatformTransactionManager`), or using declarative approach, via annotations, like spring `@Transactional` - then every SQL query issued by `JdbcTemplate` will be run outside any transaction. So yes, transactions configuration is required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wrap it using the `TransactionTemplate`

```java
transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult((TransactionStatus ts) -> {
    userService.updateUser(user);
    accountService.updateXXX(...);
});
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-prog-template