# Transaction Management for multiple datasources created manually

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am working on an application wherein I have to connect to different database depending upon an customer id that is passed from the client side. The schema for all the databases is same. It is a kind of multi-tenant application. Since I don't know how many customers will be there, I cannot use xml configuration to statically create the datasources, hence I have to create datasources manually.

We are using Spring JdbcTemplate for connecting to the databases and the connection parameter comes from another database which holds the configuration for the application. I am able to connect to the databases properly, but the method calls are not happening in a transaction.
Following is the code snippet which does the database connectivity for only one database and  I was going to extend it for multiple databases:

```
BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();
// set database connection params
....
// create jdbcTemplate, 
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
// create transaction managers
PlatformTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
```

My idea is to create the transaction manager manually and somehow bind it in the spring container so that all the methods/classes with @Transactional annotation can use this transaction manager.
I am not able to figure how do I bind the txManager, so that all the methods/classes with @Transactional will use this transaction manager. I am not sure whether this is the right way and should I be creating a transaction manager for every datasource, since, I don't want the transaction to span multiple databases, but I want that every service method call should be in a transaction.
Note: All my service classes have @Component and @Transactional annotation.

Am I solving the problem in the correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641666/springs-jdbctemplate-and-transactions

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal, thanks for your comment, but I had seen that question before posting. Using TransactionTemplate is not an efficient option for me because I lots of methods in my serivce classes and all of them will have to be wrapped using TransactionTemplate. I was looking for a solution which will be similar to the one mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of the accepted answer, but couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837601/multi-tenancy-with-spring-hibernate-sessionfactory-configured-for-multi-tena) provides what you are looking for. Otherwise, you are going to need a global transaction manager. A global transaction manager will come bundled with a JEE container, or can be provided standalone by a trnsaction manager such as Atomikos. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-global) covers both

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring's AbstractRoutingDatasource.

Please check the below link. The AbstractRoutingDatasource is explained.Here database is changed dynamically based on language selected.

[Spring AbstractRoutingDatasource](http://technicalminds.in/spring/spring-abstractroutingdatasource-multiple-schemasdb/)